# Get words from positions in string - Bash/Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following string that I want to extract name and id from and store them in a variable. This is just an example, the list can be longer but they are separated the same way.

```
[["freepbx","NEWUPDATES","There are 6 modules available for online upgrades"],["cidlookup","noauth","OpenCNAM Requires Authentication"]]
```

The id's in the string is freepbx and cidlookup, the names are NEWUPDATES and noauth.

I'd like them to come out like:

```
freepbx NEWUPDATES
cidlookup noauth
```

I'm running a program from command line that needs it's input this way.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
echo '[["freepbx","NEWUPDATES","There are 6 modules available for online upgrades"],["cidlookup","noauth","OpenCNAM Requires Authentication"]]' | sed -e 's/\],\[/\n/g' -e 's/\(\[\[\)*"//g' | awk -F ',' '{print $1, $2}'
freepbx NEWUPDATES
cidlookup noauth
```

**Explanation:**

The `sed` command `s/\],\[/\n/g` will replace all `]`, `[` which separate each record with a new line(`\n`) character. This will allow you to treat each line as a separate record which makes all other tools much easier:)

The second `sed` command `s/\(\[\[\)*"//g` will remove the quotes and the initial `[[` at the start of the first record. This cleans up things from your data leaving only the `,` between your fields.

Finally, `awk` command `-F ',' '{print $1, $2}'`, the `-F` tells `awk` to use the `,` as field separator (instead of space) and `$1` and `$2` to print the first and second fields.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'"' -v RS="\\\],\\\[" '{print $2,$4}' file

freepbx NEWUPDATES
cidlookup noauth
```

Comment: This is another way to do it ;).

Answer (score 0):

If [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is available:

```
jq -r '.[] | "\(.[0]) \(.[1])"'
```

Pipe `.[]` ( all elements in the array) output to print only 0th and 1st element `"\(.[0]) \(.[1])"`as in desired output.